# Using Find::File::Rule to find Perl scripts and exclude .bak files

Tags: perl

I am using [`Find::File::Rule`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find::Rule) to find Perl scripts. I want to exclude certain files, like test files and backup files, but I cannot make it exclude `*.bak` files if they start with a dot, for example (`p.pl`):

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dump;
use File::Find::Rule;

open(my $fh,">",".c.bak");
print $fh "#! /usr/bin/env perl\n";
close($fh);

my $rule = File::Find::Rule->new;
$rule->or(
    $rule->new->name('*.bak')->prune->discard,
    $rule->new->grep( qr/^#!.*perl\s*$/, [ sub { 1 } ] )
   );
my @files=$rule->in(".");
dd @files;
```

This gives output:

```
("p.pl", ".c.bak")
```

whereas expected output should be:

```
"p.pl"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to add another filter rule for the hidden backup files:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dump;
use File::Find::Rule;

open(my $fh,">",".c.bak");
print $fh "#! /usr/bin/env perl\n";
close($fh);

my $rule = File::Find::Rule->new;
$rule->or(
    $rule->new->name('*.bak')->prune->discard,
    $rule->new->name('.*.bak')->prune->discard,            # <== hidden backups
    $rule->new->grep( qr/^#!.*perl\s*$/, [ sub { 1 } ] )
   );
my @files=$rule->in(".");
dd @files;
```

Notice the starting `.` in the pattern.
This script will produce:

```
"p.pl"
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that files prefixed with a dot aren't matched by the '*.bak' quantifier, because they're 'hidden' files.

If you `chdir` to your directory and do `echo *` or `echo *.bak` you won't see the file there either. So effectively - that rule isn't matching, because it's a hidden file.

Solutions would be:

- new rule to explicitly match '.' files.
- regular expression match to 'name' would do the trick

Something like:

```
$rule->new->name(qr/\.bak$/)->prune->discard,
```